# How to search for installed packages which have dependancy on Python?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am looking to make a list of packages which have dependancy on Python. How to search for it ?

Another two would be that the dependency would be in *recommends* (1) or *suggests* (2) . But when Python is in *suggests* then show *suggests* only, or if Python is in *recommends* then show only those packages which have Python in *recommends*.

Comment: There is a slight difference, your question doesn't take into account those packages which are installed while mine does. I actually wanted to do it with python2 or python3 as the case maybe but that would have made it a more complex scenario.

Comment: The hard part is already done in the question, you just need to use `~i` which would search only for installed packages.

Comment: That worked - I tried `[$] aptitude search '?depends("python-gtk2") ~i'` and that worked.